# Argument parser for a word count and/or line count program

Tags: python, python-2.x, console

How to make code dry in this example? My program is working, but I want to improve it by shorting my code.
.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--words', '-w', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--lines', '-l', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('filename')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.words:
    print "Words in a file: {}" .format(print_words(args.filename))

elif args.lines:
    print "Lines in a file: {}" .format(print_lines(args.filename))

else:
    print "Words in a file: {}" .format(print_words(args.filename))
    print "Lines in a file: {}" .format(print_lines(args.filename))
```

I guess by adding a new function and putting the function call in the else statement.

I tried with the print_all function, I added the function call in the else statement.

```
def print_all(filename, args):
    for a in read_file(filename):
        if a in args:
            print "All word counts :", a
```

When I run the program using the print_all function I get:

> ```
> Namaspace(words=False, filename='someFile.txt', lines=False)
> ```

Comment: I wont the program to print both values for switches, If I don't pass a switch -w or -l when runing the program: ./wc.py someFile.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is kind of hard to understand your question, but it seems like you want the following parameters:

- `filename` – The filename to read input from
- `--words` – Show the words from the file
- `--lines` – Show the lines from the file

If both are specified, your current code will only do the first. If none are specified you'll display both. And if your question is related to avoiding the duplication of code in your else-statement, you could rework the last part of your code to this:

```
if not args.words and not args.lines:
    args.words = True
    args.lines = True

if args.words:
    print_words(args.filename)

if args.lines:
    print_lines(args.filename)
```

Notice how I've also removed the strange construction as suggested by janos...

Comment: Thanks, I should explained it better, but you read me like a book

Answer (score 3):

Do you notice something fishy on this line?

> ```
> print "Words in a file: {}" .format(print_words(args.filename))
> ```

If I highlight just the fishy part:

> ```
> print print_words(...)
> ```

The fishy part is printing something returned by `print_words`.
The name of `print_words` suggests that it prints something.
And printing functions typically don't return a value.
So this is all very confusing.

My guess is that `print_words` doesn't actually print words,
but returns a word count. So a name like `get_word_count` would be less confusing.
The same goes for `print_lines`.

With these suggested renames, now we can introduce some real printing functions, and make the code more DRY:

```
if args.words:
    print_words(args.filename)

elif args.lines:
    print_lines(args.filename)

else:
    print_words(args.filename)
    print_lines(args.filename)
```

It won't get much DRY-er than this, and I don't think it needs to.